# making module methods act like @property?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, methods, properties

I have a module with methods I'm using as follows

```
import module
print(module.location())
print(module.info2())
```

Is there a Pythonic way to turn those methods into properties, so I could do

```
print(module.location)
print(module.info2)
```

?

Comment: Not that I know, but you could make it work with `module.something.location`. Would that be enough for you?

Comment: Is the `module` 3rd party?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't actually care that a module listed in `sys.modules` is in fact a module. So it's technically possible. For example:

Define a class with those methods as properties.

```
class Module:
    @property
    def location(self):
        return _location
```

Instantiate the class.

```
module = Module()
```

Finally, replace the module reference in `sys.modules` with a reference to the instance.

```
import sys
sys.modules[__name__] = module
```

But instead, consider just writing the class and creating an instance in the module, and then import it using:

```
from module import module
```

Then it's obvious that you're getting something *from* the module, and it won't be so surprising.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python3.7+, and you control the source for `module`, you can create a `__getattr__` method on `module` to partially emulate property behaviour.

```
def _location():
    return 'here'


def _info2():
    return 'Some info'


def __getattr__(name):
    if name == 'info2':
        return _info2()
    elif name == 'location':
        return _location()
    raise AttributeError(f'No attribute {name}')

>>> import module
>>> module.location
'here'
>>> module.info2
'Some info'
```

However, there's nothing to prevent the attribute being set explicitly, overriding `__getattr__`:

```
>>> module.info2 = 'foo'
>>> module.info2
'foo'
```

The PEP for module-level `__getattr__` is [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/).